# How to make logger.trace() and logger.info() work together

Tags: java, logging, log4j, wildfly, slf4j

I have an issue logging **TRACE** function in distinct file from **INFO** function, i prepared a classic log4j.xml file containing all the required configuration.

**logger.info()** is working.
**logger.trace()** is **not** working.

```
         <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
            <param name="append" value="true" />
            <param name="file" value="C:/logs/transaction.log" />
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
            </layout>
            <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
                <param name="LevelMin" value="TRACE" />
                <param name="LevelMax" value="TRACE" />
                <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
            </filter>
        </appender>

        <appender name="fileINFO" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
            <param name="append" value="true" />
            <param name="file" value="C:/logs/server.log" />
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
            </layout>
            <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
                <param name="LevelMin" value="INFO" />
                <param name="LevelMax" value="INFO" />
                <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
            </filter>
        </appender>

        <logger name="ma.prg.net">
            <level value="trace" />
            <appender-ref ref="file" />
        </logger>

        <logger name="ma.prg.net">
            <level value="info" />
            <appender-ref ref="fileINFO" />
        </logger>
```

**logger.trace()** was working fine before i added **fileINFO** appender.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: the problem is that whenever i call logger.trace("String"), i expect to find the String in the required file pre-configured in log4j.xml but i find nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot configure the same logger twice. Just change your logger configuration to:

```
<logger name="ma.prg.net">
  <level value="trace" />
  <appender-ref ref="file" />
  <appender-ref ref="fileINFO" />
</logger>
```

With this you send the logging message to **both** appenders. But as you already configured each appender individually with *LevelMin* and *LevelMax*, each filters out the messages it should print.

Comment: You can add appenders in root tag as well, like as:
  <root>
          <priority value ="trace"/>
          <appender-ref ref="appender1"/>
          <appender-ref ref="appender2"/>
          
      </root>